Azure Function of type timer times out after 4:02 mins
I have an azure function app running in python stack with Elastic Premium (EP2) plan with 2 cores and 7GB memory.
I have 2 functions,

A timer trigger
An Http trigger

Timer function loops through a list and calls the http triggered function for each iteration.
Now http trigger runs fine, well over 20 mins, does the job and terminates successfully.
In the mean time, timer function should still keep running, but it times out after exactly 4:02 mins:
Failed to process table CALENDAR. Response: b'504.0 GatewayTimeout'

Ideally it should run till the iteration is done i.e. if list had 3 items, http triggered function should fire 3 times and then timer function should terminate. But that's not happening.
This is how the timer function looks like:
TimerFunction.py
import logging
import os
import sys
import azure.functions as func
import requests
import json
import datetime
import time

from shared.db import get_all_p6_table_names, insert_to_batch_detail

# Add the shared folder to the system path
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'shared')))

from shared.db import get_all_table_names, insert_to_batch_detail

# Set the function endpoint URL (update with the actual endpoint URL)
COPY_AND_MERGE_ENDPOINT_URL = os.getenv("COPY_AND_MERGE_ENDPOINT_URL")

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
        
    try: 
        # Fetch all table names
        tableDetails = get_all_table_names()
        logging.info(f"All Tables: {tableDetails}")
        if not tableDetails:
            logging.warning("No tables found in dbo.TableDetailsSummary")

        # Call CopyAndMergeDataFromP6ApiToDb for each table
        for table in tableDetails:
            logging.info(f"Table: {table[0]}, Project Ref field: {table[1]}")

            response = call_copy_and_merge_endpoint(table[0], table[1])
            if response.status_code != 200:
                logging.error(f"Failed to process table {table[0]}. Response: {response.content}")
                return
        logging.info("All tables processed successfully.")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        # Ensure that logging is flushed and closed after the function finishes
        logging.shutdown()

def call_copy_and_merge_endpoint(tableName, projRefField):
    batch_id = insert_to_batch_detail(tableName)

    payload = {
        'tableName': tableName,
        'projRefField': projRefField,
        'batchId': batch_id
    }
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.post(COPY_AND_MERGE_ENDPOINT_URL, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    return response

I understand that for Http triggered functions, maximum timeout is 230 seconds, but my function is timer.
Also my host.json looks like this:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "07:00:00"
}

Can anyone please help me understand if this design should work and suggest a workaround.

All Azure Functions have a timeout limit; this applies for HTTP but also for Timer triggered. Instead, you could consider pushing each individual table in your for loop into a Queue triggered Azure Function, so that only one table is processed at a time. (NB if you need this to "fan-in" again then consider Durable Functions.) See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=isolated-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#timeout and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/performance-reliability#avoid-long-running-functions
